# Problem mounting XP share using CIFS

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, mount, fstab, cifs

I've seen other similar questions but don't believe any of them solves my problem.

I've got a VMWare virtual Ubuntu box. hosted by an XP machine. The XP machine is sharing a folder `VMWebRoot`

I want to mount this shared folder to `/var/www/Dev` (I believe I should actually mount it to `/mnt` and then add a ymbolic link but one step at a time :)

I've added an entry in `/etc/hosts` with the IP/Hostname for my XP machine and can ping it with no problem.

I've added the following to fstab:

`//MyHostName/VMWebRoot /var/www/Dev cifs exec,credentials=/etc/sambapassword 0 0`

and created `/etc/sambapassword` which contains:

```
username=MyXPHostName/MyUsername
password=MyPassword
```

When I reboot the box, the system just "hangs" when it gets to the point where mounts occur during boot with no error message.

If I, from the command line run `mountall`, I get the following:

```
(...Problems mounting already mounted volumes as expected)
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
mountall: mount /var/www/Dev [3701] terminated with status 32
```

In case it was a firewall issue, I disabled the windows firewall on the XP box. Same result.

`dmesg|tail` shows:

```
CITS.VFS: No response for command 114 mid 1
CITS.VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112
```

Can someone please point me in the correct direction? I'm a complete linux newbie and have only managed to get this far through excessive Googling - I have no idea if any of this is correct / how to go about debugging.

**Edit:**

Running `smbclient //MyHostName/VMWebRoot` results in:

```
Session request to MyHostName failed (Called name not present)
Session request to *SMBSERVER failed (Called name not present)
```

Running `smbclient //MyHostIPAddress/VMWebRoot` gives:

```
Session request to 192.168.99.100 failed (Called name not present)
Session request to 192. failed (Called name not present)
Session request to *SMBSERVER failed (Called name not present)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem - It seems that `Windows File & Printer sharing` wasn't enabled for the NIC which was assigned the IP address I used.